# JavaScript functionality for Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android-studio, intellij-idea, autocomplete, hybrid-mobile-app

**See edit below.**

I want to add code completion and syntax highlighting for a custom JavaScript library in Android Studio so I can develop my hybrid app within one IDE without switching all the time.

The problem is: Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition. Therefore it does not support JavaScript out of the box as this is a feature of their Ultimate Edition. So far I haven't found any plugin yet to support the most basic JavaScript neither in Android Studio nor in IntelliJ IDEA CE.

Does anyone have either a working JavaScript plugin for Android Studio (no fancy stuff. only basic code completion  needed) or another possibility to add suport for using JavaScript libraries for code completion?

**EDIT:**

The existent answer to the question linked in the comments does not solve my problem as I found this on IntelliJ's help page for FileWatchers:

> JavaScript files generated by File Watchers are excluded from code completion and refactoring.

As JavaScript code completion is crucial to my plugin, I'm still searching for a solution. An additional problem is, that I have to find a way to "export" my changes (hopefully in form of a plug-in) so others can import and use it.

Any ideas on that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add JS and CSS support to Android Studio project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137577/add-js-and-css-support-to-android-studio-project)

Comment: I already considered that as an option for syntax highlighting but the file watcher part doesn't work for me so I would prefer some kind of plug in work around.

Comment: I always used Eclipse and the Android Studio Plugins for Hybrid development.... At which point it's rather easy to activate JavaScript syntax checking.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there is (currently) no way you can get JavaScript support in Android Studio. I didn't find any community JavaScript plugins which could be used in the Intellij Idea CE (and, therefore, Android Studio).
The only option you have is multi-IDE setup; use WebStorm for JavaScript and Android Studio for Android.

Comment: That was the result of my research, too. That's why I posted my question here. I think the problem is that Google switched from Eclipse to IntelliJ. Although it might have a more professional approach than before (eclipse + adt) IMO they lost a lot of functionality (or potential functionality) by accepting JetBrains' Terms and Conditions...

Answer (score 1):

Peter Schmalfeldt has created a repo to address this here:

https://github.com/manifestinteractive/android-studio-filetypes

Just follow the repo instruction which I quote here:

> From Android Studio Menu, go to File -> Import Settings...
>       Locate the settings.jar file from this repository
>       From "Select Components to Import" make sure you have "File types" checked, then press OK

Comment: That's the answer linked in the question I mention above. It only handles syntax highlighting. I need code completion with an option to give this completion a javascript library as a resource

Answer (score 1):

<sub>1. just copy all the plugins and configurations from IntelliJ IDEA (the free community version) folder by folder and paste it into the Android-Studio ones, not overriding existing ones, worked for me + some useful stuff like PHP debugging, this is now my goto editor <sup>(..wellllll... Notepad++... wellllll... Notepad2 then Nodepad++)</sup>




 2. Open the **A.S** <sub>*..S*</sub> , Choose `Invalidate Cache And Restart` from the `File` menu.


 3. Done.


 4. ?


 5. Profit.</sub>

Comment: That still doesn't provide code completion. There will be no solution without code completion.

Comment: try it the otherway around, copy the Android Studio to your idea one, this time don't overwrite anything, if I didn't mention it before, first, use beyondCompare and compare (well.. daa..) the text based files (ini, cfg) that are different in content but shared same name between both folders, dll and jar files can be copied freely.