# Android studio : font doesn't have a color

Tags: android-studio, react-native

I've recently installed Android studio, started to code, but my code doesn't get colorized, which is very very annoying.

Has someone an idea to solve that ?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Use IntelliJ IDEA or VSCode for react native

Comment: You should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137577/add-js-and-css-support-to-android-studio-project) out. Someone has made JS and CSS highlighting for Android Studio. 
Still, I would not recommend using Android Studio for coding the JS. Use VSCode, intellj, webstorm, atom or something that floats your boat.

Comment: thanks you very much !